# Better way of converting a Map[K, Option[V]] to a Map[K,V]

Tags: scala, collections

I have some code that is producing a `Map` where the values are `Option` types, and I really of course want a map containing only the real values.

So I need to convert this, and what I've come up with in code is

```
  def toMap[K,V](input: Map[K, Option[V]]): Map[K, V] = {
    var result: Map[K, V] = Map()
    input.foreach({
      s: Tuple2[K, Option[V]] => {
        s match {
          case (key, Some(value)) => {
            result += ((key, value))
          }
          case _ => {
            // Don't add the None values
          }
        }
      }
    })
    result
  }
```

which works, but seems inelegant.  I suspect there's something for this built into the collections library that I'm missing.

Is there something built in, or a more idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: A minor point of syntax: while the imperative foreach/+= solution is not too idiomatic, it could have been much shorter. A series of case clauses between {} makes a (partial) function, which may be passed to foreach. You could have written input.foreach{case (key, Some(value)) => ...; case _ => ...}. Also, the blocks of case clauses need not be bracketed, they end at the next case or final closing bracket.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
input.collect{case (k, Some(v)) => (k,v)}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
input flatMap {case(k,ov) => ov map {v => (k, v)}}
```

Comment: It looks better with for comprehensions: `for ((k, ov) <- input; v <- ov) yield (k,v)`

Answer (score 7):

```
for ((k, Some(v)) <- input) yield (k, v)
```

It's franza's answer from a later question, but it deserves a re-post here.