# How to convert a Map[K, Option[V]] to Map[K, V] discarding Nones in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better way of converting a Map[K, Option[V]] to a Map[K,V]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680097/better-way-of-converting-a-mapk-optionv-to-a-mapk-v)

I have a `Map[Symbol, Option[String]]` from reading values from a web page, where some might be missing.

I'd like to 'flatten' this to `Map[Symbol, String]` removing all the `None` values.

The best I can do so far is

```
def removeNones[K, V](map: Map[K, Option[V]]): Map[K, V] = 
    map.collect { case kv if kv._2.isDefined => (kv._1, kv._2.get) }
```

but I really don't like the `case`, and having to rebuild the `Pair`.

Can anyone find a nicer expression?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680097/better-way-of-converting-a-mapk-optionv-to-a-mapk-v). You can rewrite your case as simply `case (k, Some(v)) => (k, v)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, wish the SO dup finder worked as well as people do. Voted to close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
val m = Map('a -> Some("a string"), 'b -> None)

m collect {case(a, Some(b)) => (a, b)}
  // Map('a -> a string)
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: It does (http://stackoverflow.com/q/7680097/754787) but it sounds like the OP would rather not have a case, and not build a Pair. Dispensing with the case is probably feasible but inconvenient, I'm not sure one can do without the pair without resorting to a plain loop.

Comment: No, I don't mind the case if it's as elegant as that!

Answer (score 3):

I think more elegant way will be like this:

```
val map1 = Map('a -> Some("a"), 'b -> None)
val map2 = for ((k: Symbol, Some(v)) <- map1) yield (k,v)
```

Let's print the result:

```
Predef println  map2
> Map('a -> a)
```

Comment: Good answer! You don't need to the type annotation on the `Symbol` though: `for ((k, Some(v)) <- map1) yield (k, v)` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. My bad for explicit typing))